# Error While Enabling Speaker on Outgoing Call in Oreo/Nougat

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.1-nougat

I need to turn on loudspeaker during outgoing calls but its throwing exception Below is the code snippet i have used:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    if (!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn())
                        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

It is working good from devices below 6.0, but not working in 8.0 and 7.0.

**logcat:**

```
01-22 13:38:19.887 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer D/AudioManager: PPD setMode mode = 2
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.media.AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.java:1630)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.handlVibrate(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:114)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.onAccessibilityEvent(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:49)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$2.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:1527)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:1712)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
01-22 13:38:19.888 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
01-22 13:38:19.892 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer I/AudioManager: setSpeakerphoneOn true java.lang.Throwable
                                                                         at android.media.AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(AudioManager.java:1235)
                                                                         at com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.handlVibrate(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:116)
                                                                         at com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.onAccessibilityEvent(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:49)
                                                                         at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$2.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:1527)
                                                                         at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:1712)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer D/AudioManager: com.tool.autoredialerdo not have using speaker authority in call
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer D/AudioManager: PPD setMode mode = 0
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.media.AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.java:1630)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.handlVibrate(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:117)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.tool.autoredialer.services.CallVibratorAccessibilityService.onAccessibilityEvent(CallVibratorAccessibilityService.java:49)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$2.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:1527)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:1712)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-22 13:38:19.894 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
01-22 13:38:19.895 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-22 13:38:19.895 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
01-22 13:38:19.895 25014-25014/com.tool.autoredialer V/AudioManager: Elem: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: can you please add the error logs as well ?

Comment: @kshishoo i have added the logs. Please have a look at it

Comment: did you found the solution?

Comment: are you connected with bluetooth or earphones with same time?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

You are trying to use AudioManager during a call, and Android Systems forbids it. The way to achieve setting on the speaker is by replacing the Phone behaviour and implementing InCallService.

Then you may call `setAudioRoute(CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER)` and be capable of handling different devices (as such as Bluetooth or wired earphones).

You can see API definition here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#setAudioRoute(int)

Comment: Is it possible to use setAudioRoute function in TelephonyManager events?